# use the same parameters multiple times

Tags: sqlite, parameters

I have an sql-select (or insert) which uses the same two parameters several times.
Is there a way to avoid using multiple the same parameter for every "?,?,?,?,..." in the list ?

```
cursor.execute(statement, list)
```

I could think of two named parameters but without the possibility of code-injection.

In the example below every left "?" resp. right "?" is the same string. I used the seven counts in one statement in order to get one result.

```
select count(case (aart like "1%")  and (adatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as AufExt, 
       count(case (aart like "1%E") and (adatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as AufExtE,
       count(case (aart like "1%K") and (adatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as AufExtK,
       count(case (aart like "2S%") and (adatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as AufInt,
       count(case (eart like "3%")  and (edatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as EntExt, 
       count(case (eart like "3%K") and (edatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as EntExtK,
       count(case (eart like "2S%") and (edatum between ? and ?) when 1 then 1 else null end) as EntInt
from tabelle
```

Related question to this problem: It looks as if no index is used in "case". Correct?

Comment: simpler: `sum((eart like '1%') and (adatum between ? and ?))`

Comment: this works !  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) says:

> **?**     A question mark that is not followed by a number creates a parameter with a number one greater than the largest parameter number already assigned. [...]
>   **?NNN**     A question mark followed by a number *NNN* holds a spot for the *NNN*-th parameter. [...]
>   **:AAAA**     A colon followed by an identifier name holds a spot for a named parameter with the name :AAAA. Named parameters are also numbered. [...] To avoid confusion, it is best to avoid mixing named and numbered parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add with clause like this:

```
with
  parms as (select ? as parm1, ? as parm2)
```

select count(case (aart like "1%")  and (adatum between parms.parm1 and parms.parm2) when 1 then 1 else null end) as AufExt
   ...

Comment: Some "case" use adatum and some edatum.  I used these seven counts in one select-statement in order to get one result.

Comment: sory, i''m miss that